# AutoMapper - Map two external API results into one DTO object

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper, asp.net-core-webapi

I have two external endpoints, which results I need to merge into one single DTO object.
I am lost at some point as I am trying to figure out a way, how I can inject a collection of albums when only there is a match between **Album** **UserId** and **UserDetailDTO** **Id**.

Endpoint 1 - https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Endpoint 2 - https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums

Below you can find my classes:

```
public class UserDetailDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public List<Album> Albums { get; set; }
}

public class User
{ 
    [JsonProperty("id", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("username", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    [JsonProperty("userId", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("title", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public MappingProfile()
{
    var userMap = CreateMap<User, UserDetailDTO>();
    var albumMap = CreateMap<Album, UserDetailDTO>();
}
```

In the service part, I am able to get the json results from these endpoints but I am failing at the AutoMapper part.

```
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(usersResponseContent);
var albums = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Album>>(albumsResponseContent);
var mappedUsers = _mapper.Map(albums, _mapper.Map<List<User>, List<UserDetailDTO>>(users));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the mapper for assigning the albums to the DTO, you can do the below thing

```
var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(usersResponseContent);
var albums = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Album>>(albumsResponseContent);
var mappedUsers = _mapper.Map<List<User>, List<UserDetailDTO>>(users); 

foreach (var user in mappedUsers)
     user.Albums = albums.Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id);
```